# Grails Reverse Url Mapping: Is there a way to build links based on the currently matched route?

Tags: grails, reverse, url-mapping

I'm trying to build some dynamic URL mappings that are based on the domain classes of the grails project. The goal is to use a single generic controller, but the URL decides which domain is being used for processing. The problem is now, that I don't get the desired URLs when using the `<g:link />` tag.

I tried the following variants to create the URL mappings:

```
static mappings = {
    Holders.grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { 
        "/admin/${it.propertyName}/$action?/$id?"(controller: "admin")
    }
}

static mappings = {
    "/admin/$domainClass/$action?/$id?"(controller: "admin")
}
```

Both variants work for the actual URL matching. But I personally don't like the behavior of the reverse URL mapping by grails. In case of variant 1, the reverse mapping always resolves to the last added URL mapping for the AdminController. For case 2 I have the problem that I would have to pass the domainClass-Parameter to every link-creating call, even though it is theoretically not necessary, since the information is already present in the current request.

I know there is the possibility of using named URL mappings and then using something like `<g:link mapping="mapping_name" />`. The problem is that I am using some generic application-wide partial-views, where I try to only provide the necessary information for creating a link, like `<g:link action="something" />`.

This leads to my two questions:

1. Is there a possibility to get g:link to build the URL based on the matched mapping in the current request?
2. Is there a way to get a reference to the mapping that matched the current request, so I can implement to desired behavior myself?

Answer (score 1):

You could define named mappings like

```
Holders.grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { dc ->
  name((dc.propertyName):"/admin/${dc.propertyName}/$action?/$id?" {
    controller = "admin"
    domainClass = dc.propertyName
  })
}
```

With the mapping name saved in the params you can now do

```
<g:link mapping="${params.domainClass}">link text</g:link>
```